# Filling Tables by the Column

Tags: formatting, latex

Is there an easy way to enter the data inside tables in latex so that you can enter the data by column rather than by row. It is more time consuming to do it by row as I have to switch between text and math mode which makes the typing take longer. This is my current method:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        Frequency
        \newline (Hz)
        &
        I on $R_1$
        \newline (Ohms)
        &
        I on C
        \newline (Ohms)
        &
        I on $R_2$
        \newline (Ohms)
        \\
        \hline
        10
        &
        $3.9 \times 10^-7$
        &
        0.0000
        &
        0.0001
        \\
        \hline
        
        100
        &
        $2.78 \times 10^-5$
        &
        0.0005
        &
        0.0007
        \\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:SingleLoopTable3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `pgfplots` package. There you can read in the data from external files.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a better way haha

Comment: ... or more precisely `pgfplotstable`. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool might also be worth a look.